# How to enable ItemWriter to write items to database when rows are locked by ItemReader?

Tags: spring-batch

I defined a simple job that should read records from the database, process items and update/write to the status column for successfully processed items.

The writer gets stuck (when committing the transaction when trying to write a chunk) because the itemReader already locks the table.
The ItemReader input is defined by this query:

```
SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED LIMIT 500
```

How to enable ItemWriter to write items to the database when ItemReader locks rows?

I've tried defining a custom `PlatformTransactionManager` bean as

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(final DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: You should find out if your database is locking the entire table or a specific row, and lets say even with 1 row, you can not avoid locking if you are reading/writting to the same object at the same time.... therefore implement Retry on your job.

Comment: @JCompetence could you clarify this a bit, how will implementing Retry in my job help solve this issue?

Comment: The database should lock only specific rows that are matched by the SELECT query. What I find strange is that even though the Spring Batch docs say that reading and writing happens in one transaction, the writer is not allowed to change rows locked by the reader.

Comment: I've tried executing the SQL statements specified in my Reader and Writer manually in the console in the same transaction. The `SELECT` query locks rows and `UPDATE` is allowed to update the same rows with desired values without any issues.

Comment: @Goran It should be possible. Do you use PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, I use the latest available PostgreSQL image in my docker-compose file.

Comment: I've debugged this issue a bit and found out that the thread hangs in `org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore()`, at this line: `read = wrapped.read(buffer, endIndex, canFit)`. it seems it is just waiting for more data from the server, but I don't know what it expects to receive.

Comment: If you package your sample in a github repo I can take a look.

Comment: @Goran I was able to reproduce the issue. This is related to the `useSharedExtendedConnection` parameter of the `JdbcCursorItemReader`. I added an answer with more details and a complete example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the `useSharedExtendedConnection` parameter of the `JdbcCursorItemReader`. By default, the cursor will be opened using its connection and will not participate in any transactions started for the rest of the step processing. Hence the issue you are facing.

You need to set that parameter to `true` and wrap your data source in an `ExtendedConnectionDataSourceProxy` which is provided by Spring Batch (as described in the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/AbstractCursorItemReader.html#setUseSharedExtendedConnection(boolean))).

Here is a complete example (based on Spring Batch 5.0.3 and TestContainers, which you can add [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/core/test/repository) for a quick test):

```java
/*
 * Copyright 2020-2023 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.batch.core.test.repository;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ExtendedConnectionDataSourceProxy;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.DataClassRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringJUnitConfig;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

/**
 * @author Mahmoud Ben Hassine
 */
@Testcontainers(disabledWithoutDocker = true)
@SpringJUnitConfig
class PostgreSQLJobRepositoryIntegrationTests {

    private static final DockerImageName POSTGRESQL_IMAGE = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:13.3");

    @Container
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer<>(POSTGRESQL_IMAGE);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        databasePopulator.addScript(new ClassPathResource("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-postgresql.sql"));
        databasePopulator.execute(this.dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.execute("create table person (id bigint not null primary key, name varchar not null, processed boolean)");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into person (id, name, processed) values (1, 'foo1', false)");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into person (id, name, processed) values (2, 'FOO2', true)");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into person (id, name, processed) values (3, 'bar1', false)");
        jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into person (id, name, processed) values (4, 'BAR2', true)");
    }

    @Test
    void testJobExecution() throws Exception {
        // given
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().toJobParameters();

        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = this.jobLauncher.run(this.job, jobParameters);

        // then
        assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
        jdbcTemplate
                .query("select * from person", new DataClassRowMapper<>(Person.class))
                .forEach(person -> System.out.println("person = " + person));
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    static class TestConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
            PGSimpleDataSource datasource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
            datasource.setURL(postgres.getJdbcUrl());
            datasource.setUser(postgres.getUsername());
            datasource.setPassword(postgres.getPassword());
            return new ExtendedConnectionDataSourceProxy(datasource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTransactionManager(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> itemReader(DataSource dataSource) {
            String sql = "select * from person where processed = false for update skip locked limit 2";
            return new JdbcCursorItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
                    .name("personItemReader")
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .sql(sql)
                    .beanRowMapper(Person.class)
                    .useSharedExtendedConnection(true)
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemProcessor<Person, Person> itemProcessor() {
            return person -> new Person(person.getId(), person.getName().toUpperCase(), true);
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
            String sql = "update person set name = :name, processed = :processed where id = :id";
            return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                    .dataSource(dataSource)
                    .sql(sql)
                    .beanMapped()
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, JdbcTransactionManager transactionManager,
                       JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> itemReader, ItemProcessor<Person, Person> itemProcessor, JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter) {
            return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
                .start(new StepBuilder("step", jobRepository)
                    .<Person, Person>chunk(2, transactionManager)
                        .reader(itemReader)
                        .processor(itemProcessor)
                        .writer(itemWriter)
                    .build())
                .build();
        }

    }

    public static final class Person {
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private boolean processed;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(int id, String name, boolean processed) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.processed = processed;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isProcessed() {
            return processed;
        }

        public void setProcessed(boolean processed) {
            this.processed = processed;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (obj == this) return true;
            if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) return false;
            var that = (Person) obj;
            return this.id == that.id &&
                    Objects.equals(this.name, that.name) &&
                    this.processed == that.processed;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id, name, processed);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person[" +
                    "id=" + id + ", " +
                    "name=" + name + ", " +
                    "processed=" + processed + ']';
        }
    }

}
```

Note how the sample hangs as you described when the `useSharedExtendedConnection` is not set and the datasource is not wrapped in a `ExtendedConnectionDataSourceProxy`.

Comment: That's it, it works as expected now! Thanks a lot Mahmoud!

Comment: Glad it helped! You are welcome. In that case, please accept the answer to let other people in the same case know that this solved your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you.